# How do you format UITextFields with constraints?

Tags: ios5

I have started putting some validation in the text fields.  There must be an easier way than writing every possible check.

There are two things I'd like to do:

1. I need the user to type in a year.  I have set the keyboard to numeric.  how can I limit the length to max of 4, check to see if it is in the past < than current year, etc...
2. Just want to limit the length of another entry to 7 characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you would use the UITextField delegate
set the delegate on the uitextfield and then implement these methods into your class

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

then check whenever that updates if the string will be less than or equal to 4 characters and do any other sort of checks as to what will be changed nd return `YES` if you want to allow it and `NO` if not

Comment: thanks, is there no way to force a text field to conform to a format upon initializing?